Customize Vaadin oldbrowser page
Is there a way to customize or localize the 'oldbrowser'-page which is shown to unsupported browsers like IE via the url parameter ?v-r=oldbrowser?
It currently shows the text 'I'm sorry, but your browser is not supported' but I would like to customize the text and add a logo.
All I've found was the method redirectToOldBrowserPageWhenNeeded() in the IndexHtmlRequestHandler class which basically adds the v-r=oldbrowser url parameter.
I'm using Vaadin 24.

The class handling this is
UnsupportedBrowserHandler,
which basically tries to load a resource with the name
browser-too-old.html.
The easy route is to put the file in your resources folder
of your project (or any other appropriate directory, where files end up
in the root of the class-path).
If you already have hooked into the "more complex" features to load
a resource (most likely not, because integration with Spring etc.
already does that for you), make sure the file can be found.
